# Is there a faster way of refreshing newly inserted items than reloadData in NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

When adding a row to my `NSOutlineView` I'm calling `reloadData` to refresh the `NSOutlineView`, like so:

```
[m_dataSource add:...];  // first add item to my data source
[m_outlineView reloadData];
```

Unfortunately, `reloadData` seems to be very slow when called for every row that is inserted. Inserting 1000 rows that way takes about a minute here because `reloadData` is called 1000 times as well.

So is there any faster method that could be used to tell `NSOutlineView` to refresh after inserting a row?

Comment: What does the doc say about `NSOutlineView`'s `reloadData` or `reloadItem`?

Comment: You don't have to call `reloadData` if you add rows to the outline view with `insertItemsAtIndexes:inParent:withAnimation:`. Are the 1000 rows added in the same iteration of the runloop?

Answer (score 1):

On can hope that Apple will add a *diffable data source* to `NSOutlineView`, like it exists for [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewdiffabledatasource), in the meantime you can try these projects: [shpakovski/OutlineViewDiffableDataSource](https://github.com/shpakovski/OutlineViewDiffableDataSource) or [stevesparks/OutlineViewDiffableDataSource](https://github.com/stevesparks/OutlineViewDiffableDataSource)